# How to change text of fragment when switch page?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have fragment header like this:

```html
<div class="header" th:fragment="user_header_info (vm)">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- logo -->
        <div class="logo-container">
            <div class="logo">
                <a th:href="@{'/home'}">
                    <img th:src="@{/images/logo.png}" alt="logo">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="header-title">
            <p>
                Login
            </p>
        </div>
        <!-- search -->
        <div class="search-container">
            <div class="search">
                <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Tìm kiếm">
                <button class="search-button"><span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```html
<div th:replace="fragments/header"></div>
```

How can I change text of header-title when open Home page to "home", or register page to "register"? Please help me!

Comment: You can pass the page title as a param to the fragment

Comment: use Jquery to check the page type and change the title